# CodeIgniter - Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-2

I have just started using codeigniter, PHP and facing issue while trying to build UI dynamically by fetching data from DB:

**Requirement:**
I need to create a list of parent - child dynamically by reading info from DB. 
I have two tables admin_menu and admin_menu_item. Admin menu contains parent menu options and admin_menu_item contains each parent's detail option. admin_menu_item has AD_MENU_ID column storing parent's id giving me hierarchical structure.

**My Controller:**

class Home extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('array');
$this->load->model('Menu');
$header_data['base_url'] = base_url(); 
    $data['menu'] = $this->Menu->get_admin_menu_data();

    $data['menu_item'] = array();
foreach($data['menu'] as $row){
 array_push($data['menu_item'], 
     $this->Menu->get_admin_menu_item_data($row->ad_menu_id));
}
            $this->load->view('homepage/header');
    $this->load->view('homepage/admin_menu',$data);
}
```

}

Here is the structure of the code

**My Model:**

```
class Menu extends CI_Model{

function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_admin_menu_data()
{
    $this->db->select('ad_menu_id,ad_menu_name');
    $query = $this->db->get('admin_menu');
    return $query->result();
}

function get_admin_menu_item_data($menu_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT ad_menu_item_name FROM ADMIN_MENU_ITEM WHERE AD_MENU_ID = " . $menu_id);

    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        return $query->result();
      }
}
```

}

When I use $data variable in my view I get a blank parent row resulting in an extra item where parent doesn't have a value and I get following error

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: homepage/admin_menu.php
Line Number: 9

which is basically my view line where I access parent element

**My View:**

```
      echo "<ul class=\"accordion\" id=\"accordion-1\">";
        foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {
        print "<li class=\"dcjq-current-parent\">"; //add li tag
        print "<a href=\"#\">" . $value->ad_menu_name . "</a>\n";

        print "<ul>";                
        foreach($menu_item as $key_item => $value_item){
              print "<li><a href=\"#\">";
              print  $value_item->ad_menu_item_name . "</a></li>\n";
              $action_type = '';
        }//end of menu item for each
       print "</ul></li>\n";
      }//end of menu for each
        print "</ul>";
```

Sorry, for the long post but I am really stuck here and cannot figure out what is wrong with this?

**Update:**

I was finally able to make it work ny changing the code in model and view. The issue was objects within objects causing the hierarchy to become too complex. 
The final solution was to make just one database call and process data in the view.
Thanks Yan for working with me and guiding to the solution.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($menu_item)` on your view?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have two different objects in the $menu variable in the view which is not recommened. My suggestion is to send one of them as a second parameter to the view.

Notice how you are overwriting the data in `'$data['menu']['menu_item']'` with each iteration of the foreach loop.

In the controller:

```
$data['menu_item'] = array();
foreach($data['menu'] as $row){
     array_push($data['menu_item'], 
         $this->Menu->get_admin_menu_item_data($row->ad_menu_id));
}
```

In the view:

```
foreach ($menu_item as $key => $value) {
        print "<li class=\"dcjq-current-parent\">"; //add li tag
        print "<a href=\"#\">" . $value->ad_menu_name . "</a>\n";
}
```

EDIT:
The solution was merging the SQL queries:

```
SELECT ADMIN_MENU_ITEM 
.ad_menu_item_name FROM ADMIN_MENU_ITEM JOIN admin_menu ON ADMIN_MENU_ITEM.AD_MENU_ID = admin_menu.ad_menu_id
```

Comment: How can I send two parameter to the view??

Comment: I have added my view code to the post. Your solution works for the controller part where I was overwriting the array but I am not sure how to access this structure in the view.

Comment: add another variable. Every cell in the $data variable is a variable by itself in the view. Notice how I created in the controller a cell in the $data variable called $data['menu_item']. In the view the variable is called $menu_item.

Comment: I am still getting following error even after changing the code my view to what you have suggested ............A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: homepage/admin_menu.php
Line Number: 10

Comment: please var_dump($menu_item) in the view. Is it populated?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10668/discussion-between-yan-and-user1017268)

Answer (score 1):

i'am have same problem
how to fix error Message: Trying to get property of non-object
if i'am inject "-" from URL.

to fix edit your artikel_model.php

```
function get_by_id($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_artikel', array('id' => $id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->row();
    }else{
    print_r('No Found Artikel');
    error_reporting(0);
    }
}
```

print_r('No Found Artikel'); <-- if URL not found show this message

error_reporting(0);  <-- to hiden error report

./eoc